# Update Toggle Switch from js handler LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield, session

I've an Input toggle field which needs to be updated from sessionstorage.

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle" onchange={changeToggle} label="Record Exists" value={relPrjToggle} checked={isActive} message-toggle-active="Enabled" message-toggle-inactive="Inactive"></lightning-input> <br/>
```

When the toggle switch is updated by the user, i'm setting the values to sessionstorage from onchnage in JS.
changeToggle(event){
this.isActive = !this.isActive;

```
     this.relPrjToggle = this.isActive;
     
     console.log('toggle change:::::'+this.isActive);
     /*Set Values to sessionstorage to retrive on load*/
     sessionStorage.setItem("prjToggle", this.isActive);
 }
```

When the user comes back to same page, I need to get the previous values from session and show the LWC. So in ConnectCallback(), I try to get the variable likebelow,

```
connectedCallback() {
 this.isActive = sessionStorage.getItem("prjToggle",this.isActive);
}
```

In console.log statements, I see that I'm getting correct values but the UI is not reflecting it. Toggle always stays on even when I get false from session.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sessionStorage` (and `localStorage`) serialize properties into strings when you use `setItem`. This matters because `false` becomes `"false"` when you store it, so when you get it back out, it's the string `"false"`, which is actually a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value in JavaScript. You would want to check if the value from `getItem` is actually `"true"`.

```
this.isActive = sessionStorage.getItem("prjToggle") === "true";
```

[Demo](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/mZLxwRBpaY6mq8pnivtq/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: it worked @sfdcfox. Thank you for helping